# What are source and resource root in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, resources, terminology

I'm developing a project about NLP. I have a large corpus and some code. I want to separate them in my project but I'm wondering what is the correct names to choose,

- **data vs code** like in data segment and code segment in assembly, or
- **source and resource** as one of my friends insists is the correct term.

I also saw something in pycharm menus as `mark as source`, `mark as resource` which I supposed is explained in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) but I still can't understand what are these source and resource root things and when should I use them. I used to think of resource as time, energy, computational power etc.

Comment: Mb that will help other people: u can check what `Source roots` does by simply marking any folder, restarting PyCharm and trying to use autoimports. And u'll see that PyCharm chooses the path relative to the folder marked as `Source roots`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

answers from JetBrains [Content root types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types)

> ### Content root types
>
> By default, all the files in a content root folder are involved in indexing, searching, parsing, code completion, and so on. To change this status, folders within a content root can be assigned to the following categories:
>
> **Regular content roots**, created as described in Configuring Project Structure. These roots are marked the Content root icon.
>
> A content root is a folder that contains the files that make up your
> project.
>
> **Source roots** (or source folders; shown as the Source root icon ). These roots contain the actual source files and resources. PyCharm
> uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports.
>
> The files under the source roots are interpreted according to their
> type. PyCharm can parse, inspect, index, and compile the contents of
> these roots.
>
> **Resource roots** (PyCharm Professional only) or resource folders; shown as the Resources root icon the Resources root icon. These roots
> are intended for resource files in your application (images, style
> sheets, and so on). By assigning a folder to this category, you tell
> PyCharm that files in it and in its subfolders can be referenced
> relative to this folder instead of specifying full paths to them.
>
> **Excluded roots** (shown as the Excluded root icon) are ones that PyCharm "almost ignores". These roots contain files and folders
> ignored by PyCharm when indexing, searching, parsing, watching and so
> on.
>
> **Excluded roots** are not visible to PyCharm. Usually, one would like to exclude temporary build folders, generated output, logs, and other
> project output. Excluding the unnecessary paths is a good way to
> significantly improve performance.
>
> **Template roots** (PyCharm Professional only) marked as the Template Folder icon contain templates for the various web projects.

Answer (score 2):

"Resource" is a more general term than "data". By "data" one usually means the *input* to a program, something that will influence its output and which can be different in each execution.

But there are other types of files that have a more permanent function, for example the icon images used by a program's graphical interface. This type of file would also be placed in a resource directory because it needs to be accessed during execution to assemble the interface. Another example of resources could be translation files (each translation file containing the translated messages used by the program in a specific language).

By those definitions, your text corpuses can be seen as "data" since you might want to apply your program to different corpuses in the future, or as a "resource" if they are more fixed and used as a sort of reference for the program to solve queries based on other user input.

Naturally we can also see things like icon image files as "data" if we plan to change them often and regard them as the input to our program, but that would be atypical.

Overall the boundary between "data" and "resources" are kind of blurry but that would be the overall idea.