# PyCharm add Python extra path: Custom module path for missing import resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, bazel

I'm coming from VSCode into PyCharm as my team wants me to use PyCharm. It's a hard requirements.

In my current python project, I have a python code where we didn't commit all the generated (grpc) python code. To generate this, let's say we run a command like: `bazel build //...`

The project will run only if you use bazel, but bear with me. It's supposedly not a complex question.

The directory looks like this:

```
- workspaceFolder (source root)
|-- models
  |-- dao_user.py
  |-- dao_accounts.py
|-- database
  |-- transaction.py
  |-- google_spanner.py
|-- service
  |-- grpc_user_svc.py
...
|-- .bazel-bin (auto-generated by bazel build)
  |-- api
    |-- protos
      |-- awesome_pb2.py
      |-- awesome_service_pb2.py
      |-- authentication.py
```

However, this will output the generated code into a different folder inside `${workspaceFolder}/.bazel-bin/`. Of course, this should give an issue in the PyCharm interpreter code where we would be missing some imports because the python code is not in the workspace folder (a.k.a the project source root).

```py
# Pycharm has issues finding this modules
from api.protos.authentication import AuthenticationRequest 
from api.protos import awesome_pb2 as api_awersome_pb2
from api.protos import awesome_service_pb2
```

My question is, how can tell PyCharm to get the above imports to be analysed from `.bazel-bin` folders?

- I don't want to move the code from `.bazel-bin`.
- I want PyCharm interpreter to understand the extra source code path from `.bazel-bin/`

I'm pretty sure it's possible. I have made it work in VSCode.
I can do this in VSCode by having the following configuration settings:

```json
// .vscode/settings.json
{ 
 "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/api",
    "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/cloud",
    "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-bin/storage"
  ],
  "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
  "python.linting.pydocstyleEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.banditEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
  "python.linting.prospectorEnabled": false,
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": false,
}
```

My team also doesn't know how to do this in PyCharm.

Comment: I also found related issues: (1) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009882279-Unresolved-references-when-specifying-2-sources-root 

(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680350/what-are-source-and-resource-root-in-pycharm

Comment: yes i have the same issue as well, can't believe no one faced this issue before

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this.

- Sources root (a blunt hammer):

  If your project is structured like:

  [image]

  Right click the `.bazel-bin` folder -> Mark Directory As -> Sources Root and pycharm will find it:

  [image]
- Interpreter Paths:

  File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> dropdown -> Show all -> Show Interpreter Paths -> + -> add the `.bazel-bin` directory:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

click "Ok" all the way out of all the sub windows and pycharm should find your files now.

Comment: somehow I still can't get this to work, but still thanks for the detailed guide. maybe there's something wrong with my folder structure, I think if I try rearrange my folders to look like yours then that'd probably be good.

Comment: do you have all the required `__init__.py`'s?